# How to extract file names of type .qvd from a directory and set it in a variable one by one using Windows command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some files of `.qvd` type in a directory. So what I want is to extract the file names (without the extension) one by one of all the `.qvd` type files and send that variable value as a parameter to another batch file.

So in the first loop the variable will have the first file name and the CALL function will call another batch and pass the first file name in the variable. Similarly the loop will go on until the last file name of `.qvd` type has been fetched.

I am using command line to write it as below:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %f in (E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs\*.qvd) do (
    CALL CSV_Gene.bat %~nf E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs E:\QVD_to_CSV\CSVs
)
```

But this doesn't execute and just close on running this batch.

Comment: The first argument  you pass are the attributes of the .qvd file not the name. See [for /?](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for the proper `~` modifier.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you said...

Comment: `%~af` returns the attributes of the file currently iterated by the for loop. To get the fullname use `%~ff`. If you'd clicked on the link I provided or viewed the output of `for /?` in a console you already knew.

Comment: If the filename may have spaces then advise double quoting `%~nf`. **Note**: Conditions between using *batch-file* and *cmd* may vary as to doubling of `%` etc. *cmd* is `%~nf` while *batch-file* is `%%~nf`.

Comment: The problem was that I was not using %% before the arguments. As i was running the script in a batch file so double %'s must be used to fetch the file names using the parameters.

Comment: Yep. You could have spent about 20 seconds reading the help file for the FOR command as it states that usage on about the 7th line.

Answer (score 1):

The help of command **FOR** is output on running in an opened command prompt window `for /?`.
The help output on several pages explains on first page:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.

And the output help contains also:

> In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional syntax:
>
> ```
>     %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
>     %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
>     %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
>     %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
>     %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
>     %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
>     %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
>     %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
>     %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
>     %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
>     %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                    environment variable and expands %I to the
>                    fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                    If the environment variable name is not
>                    defined or the file is not found by the
>                    search, then this modifier expands to the
>                    empty string
> ```

So the command line used directly in a command prompt window for this task is:

```
for %I in (E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs\*.qvd) do @call CSV_Gene.bat "%~nI" E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs E:\QVD_to_CSV\CSVs
```

And the same command line in a batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs\*.qvd) do call CSV_Gene.bat "%%~nI" E:\QVD_to_CSV\QVDs E:\QVD_to_CSV\CSVs
```

A file name containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` requires to be enclosed in double quotes which is the reason for using `"%~nI"` respectively `"%%~nI"`.

There is no need for delayed environment variable expansion for this task. For that reason this special mode is not used for faster batch file execution and handle also file names with one or more exclamation marks correct.